# What is the equivalent of "git pull <repo> <refspec>" in JGit?

Tags: git, jgit

I'm using JGit version `5.3.0.201903130848-r` and I'm trying to figure out how to do a `git pull <repo> <refspec>`.

I was expecting the `PullCommand` to have a `setRefSpecs` method similarly to the `FetchCommand`, but it doesn't.

Does it mean the only way is doing a fetch + merge, i.e. something like :

```scala
// Scala example
val gitRepo = new Git(repository)
gitRepo
      .fetch()
      .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("HEAD:refs/head/master"))
      .setRemote("origin")
      .call()

gitRepo.merge().call()
```

Comment: Yes, if you look at the implementation of PullCommand, FetchCommand is used, but setRefSpecs() is not used at all, so there is currently no way to do this with PullCommand directly.